# How do I start the an activity when user doesn't use it anymore

Tags: android, timer, handler

I have two activities in my app, first activity leads to second and the second leads back to the first. In the second one he can record and message and leave his name. In case the user only uses the second activity and just walks away I want that it jumps automatically to the first one after 20 seconds. Do I have to use a Handler for that? Because if I use

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  // my code 
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(r,20000);
        }
    });
```

It will change the activity independently from the user input? Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: When do you want to redirect user to the first activity exactly or after what action?

Comment: Do you want the app to redirect from second to first if the second is IDLE for 20 seconds?

Comment: exactly, if the second screen is not being used at all for 20 seconds then I want it to get redirected to the first activity/screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the user left his name in run(). If there is a name, do not execute the code that starts the other activity.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (textViewName.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    // my code 
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r,20000);
    }
});
```

Comment: This works thank you! However, I have a recording function AND a getName function how do I combine both in my if clause? I tried
if (mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0 && btnClick.OnClick()==0)
but that doesn't work

Comment: So you want to check if a button was pressed?

Comment: Yes. so the first function is for leaving an audio file the second for the name. But if the the user just walks away and does not do anything then she activity should jump to the first one again

Comment: Oh ok, so I created an int = 0 and when the recording button is pressed it will get the value of 1. So now in my if statement looks like this  (mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0 && a==0) and it works.

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to detect if a button was pressed. Normally you just use a boolean for that. boolean wasPressed = false; and when the button is pressed wasPressed = true; your if statement: (mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0 && !wasPressed)